# Valuing a parameter in a query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a variable where IDs are passed in the itemdatabound event and I want to use that id as a parameter for the select in sqldatasource, I don't know how to do it

this is the event:

```
    protected void ListView2_ItemDataBound(object sender, 
    ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Label ID;
            ID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ID");
            ID.Font.Italic = true;

            System.Data.DataRowView view = e.Item.DataItem as 
            System.Data.DataRowView;

        }
    }
```

This is sqldatasource:

```
    protected void SqlDataSource5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT ID, RagioneSociale, Email, Piva FROM 
        Persona WHERE Tipocliente = 2 AND ID_Società = @ID";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
using( var cmd  = new SqlCommand(query,con)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", "this.ID");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

See this as well:

Create an int variable outside of the event.

```
private int iD;
```

Then modify the access level of the event from    protected to private or public, you can even leave it as void.

```
private void ListView2_ItemDataBound(object sender, 
ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Label ID;
        ID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ID");
        ID.Font.Italic = true;
        this.iD  = Convert.ToInt32(ID)
        System.Data.DataRowView view = e.Item.DataItem as 
        System.Data.DataRowView;

    }
}
```

(I am answering from phone so I hope you can forgive the half answers and long wait)

Comment: it can't be just that

Comment: What is this.ID?

Comment: In your case its the ID passed from itemdatabound event after you cast it to int or convert it to int.

Comment: if I put the private event, I get a mistake in the aspx

Comment: gives me this error in the conversion:
Cannot cast objects of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' on type 'System.IConvertible'. '